# Wordpress insert javascript, error with $

Tags: javascript, wordpress, typeerror

I have a wordpress page. And I want to insert a typo javascript. I read other similar questions and I tried to do it like them, but it still dont work.
On the page it have an error at the console window which says: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typed is not a function` and shows the `$("#slidertext").typed({` part to be wrong. Am I misspelled something?

Here is the `header.php` where the file inserted:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/typo/insertjs.php";
include_once($path);
```

And the `insertjs.php` file:

```
<script src="/typo/typed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $("#slidertext").typed({
        //strings: ["Luxus.", "Extravagancia.", "Profizmus.", "Try it  out!"],
        stringsElement: $('#texts'),
        typeSpeed: 30,
        backDelay: 500,
        loop: false,
        contentType: 'html', // or text
        // defaults to false for infinite loop
        loopCount: false,
        callback: function(){ foo(); },
        resetCallback: function() { newTyped(); }
    });

    $(".reset").click(function(){
        $("#slidertext").typed('reset');
    });

});

function newTyped(){ /* A new typed object */ }

function foo(){ console.log("Callback"); }
</script>

<div id="texts">
<p>Luxus.</p>
<p>Extravagancia.</p>
<p>Profizmus.</p>
</div>
```

The `typed.js` is very similar to [this](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/blob/master/js/typed.js).

Answer (score 0):

Your typed.js is not loading. Please give it full path:

```
<script src="/typo/typed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Like

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/typo/typed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What if it's localhost? Loading a resource with an absolute URL is not a good idea. She should better find the right relative url. But the script doesn't seem to load, I agree on that.

Comment: I changed it to relative url now.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the solutions worked.
But I tought about how maybe the problem is with the `jquery.js`?
Where I saw the typed.js, on the index.html they called the
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
But when I call it in `insertjs.php` the Wonderplugin Slider is disappears.
The errors:
`Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).wonderpluginslider is not a function`
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typed is not a function`
Maybe the right question is how to call `jquery.min.js`?

Comment: please try  $(...).wonderpluginslider instaed of jQuery(...).wonderpluginslider

Comment: @AtifTariq 
Unfortunately that neither works. =(
The error: `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`
This is how look liked before:
`jQuery(".wonderpluginslider").wonderpluginslider();`
And I changed here the `jQuery` to `$`.
In the `wonderpluginsliged.js` jQuery can be found total 23. If I change every of them the error is:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined(anonymous function)` in wonderpluginslider.js

Comment: Can you please share URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try NoConflict :

```
$=jQuery.noConflict();
```